# Переклад слова "витальность"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Харуки Мураками «О чем я говорю, когда говорю о беге»:

> И, тем не менее, я твердо намерен держаться до последнего, чтобы
>   момент, когда моей ***витальности*** уже не хватит на сопротивление
>   внутреннему яду, наступил как можно позже.

В [Російсько-українських словниках](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) дане слово відсутнє.

[Философская энциклопедия](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_philosophy/1947/%D0%92%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%AC)

> ***ВИТАЛЬНОСТЬ*** (от лат. vita жизнь)  жизненная сила (см. Витализм); (большая или
>   меньшая) сила жизненной функции.

[Російсько-український словник сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> • Жизненная сила – *життьова сила*; живець.

Чи можна перекласти ***"витальность"*** одним словом? Яким саме?

Comment: Словник іншомовних слів Мельничука (http://slovopedia.org.ua/42/53394/279414.html): ВІТАЛЬНИЙ віта́льний (лат. vitalis) - біол. життєвий, прижиттєвий; той, що стосується життєвих явищ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вище навів п. Artemiх [словник іншомовних слів Мельничука](http://slovopedia.org.ua/42/53394/279414.html):

> **ВІТАЛЬНИЙ** віта́льний (лат. vitalis) біол. життєвий, **прижиттєвий**; той, що стосується життєвих явищ.

Ймовірно, звідси й утворюємо ***вітальність - прижиттєвість, життєвість***.

У [СУМі-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=169645&page=483) подають аналогічно, але спершу до відсилання до **"вітальний 2"**:

> **ВІТА́ЛЬНІСТЬ** , ності, ж. *Властивість за знач. **віта́льний 2***. Повнота життя, вітальність, нічим не стримуваний активізм для В. Винниченка важливіші за крихкі й відносні моральні категорії(з наук. літ.);
>
> **ВІТА́ЛЬНИЙ2**, а, е. 2. біол. **Життєвий, прижиттєвий**; той, що стосується життєвих явищ; необхідний для життя. Той “паралельний” Львів, у якому жив Андрухович і в середохресті якого товклося чимало іншого люду, був головним або й узагалі єдиним об'єктом прикладання інтелектуальної, творчої та іншої вітальної енергії(із журн.).

На [цьому](https://classes.ru/all-ukrainian/dictionary-ukrainian-explanatory-term-25440.htm) сайті у Тлумачному словнику української мови ще пропонується так:

> **ВІТАЛЬНІСТЬ** -ності, ж., психол.
>
> 1) Здатність залишатися живим.
>
> 2) **Рух**, **дія** або **сила**.

Answer (score 0):

В українській мові вживається слово майже співзвучне з російським [**вітальність]**(http://www.big-lib.com/book/2_Filosofiya_prava/224_43Antropologema_vitalnosti):

> **Вітальність** людини являє собою сукупність вроджених властивостей і здатностей, які забезпечують її життя в природі.

Цей термін часто використовують у [просторах інтернету](http://poradumo.pp.ua/cikave/59802-vtalnst-ce-stan-zhittyevoyi-aktivnost.html).

Більше інформації про це слово можна знайти у [Європейському словнику філософії: Лексикон неперекладностей. Т. 2](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=qscV6idz6AAC&pg=PA388&lpg=PA388&dq=%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85&source=bl&ots=P2j-6YqwSj&sig=nD9rTdryPpb6XWLn2ixn_B7CZrM&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPrqjn5IjcAhUGWSwKHTklCxsQ6AEIaTAJ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85&f=false), де вказані такі синоніми: **плинний, живий**.